# Http Error code 302 getting when running

Tags: java, php, json

I use this php code to write java code for some task

```
$data_array =  array(
            'mail'=>'****.com',
            'profile_first_name' => 'Sidath'
            );
$json_data = json_encode($data_array);
$request = new HTTP_Request2('**************');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST)
   ->addPostParameter(array(
        'data' => $json_data,   
    )
);
```

This is the java code i wrote

```
URL url = new URL("*******.xml");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8\"");

            String input = "{\"mail\":\"****@gmail.com\",\"profile_first_name\" : \"jjsjds\"}";

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();
```

After running this java code it gives http error 302. But php code is working fine. Why this java code returns 302

Answer (score 0):

Did you check to see if you are authenticated ? 302 is a redirect. It is probably to sign-on page.

Comment: No but php code run with out authentication. It sends only the data to the .xml file. And it works. But java code gives 302.